# One Django model field as array of strings and another field as dropdown with choices from first field?

Tags: python, django-models

How can I make first_names store an array of strings and `primary_first_name` be a drop down where it is possible to choose one of the strings in the `first_names` array.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_names = ?
    primary_first_name = ?
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I am using Django REST framework in case it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a dropdown you need to use `Model.CharField` with [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices).

For the `first_names` - please consider using relations. Array of strings can be represented as One To Many relationship. For that you will need another model which will store the values. You will then use [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) on that model.

You can use [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) if you are using PostgreSQL. But using that would not allow using other databases in the future.